# Ionic 2 "ionic run android" produces very large APK on device?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, crosswalk-runtime

What influences APK size?

I have simple Angular 2 app using typescript, which compiles to 2mb of javascript total.

The app has 387MB in size.

I noticed that in /platforms/android/build is 587MB, inside I have dirs:
intermediates  453MB
outputs  109MB
generated 0.5MB
tmp 24kb

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I am using Crosswalk, but it should add 20MB, not 350MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

APK is just zip archive, you could open it and check content.

Comment: I did that, I have 569MB in /assets/www/resouces/platforms/android/build/, in there I have 3 directories:   generated-96kb, intermediates, 454mb, outputs 114mb.   Did I forgot to put some "production" switch on?

Comment: You should check  intermediates and outputs, which files are there?